# How to display post excerpt beside post list inside Post of Dashboard

Tags: posts, excerpt, dashboard

I need to display a little description of the posts on the post lists page, i.e inside Post page of admin dashboard. It is already displaying title, author, categories, tags, comment, date, and so on. but how can i fetch post excerpt to be displayed here beside title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add follwing line of code in your theme's function.php to display a new column which will display excerpt in your posts.

```
function pkb_get_excerpt($post_ID) {
    $content_post = get_post($post_ID);
$content = $content_post->post_content;
    if ($content) {
      return $content;
    }
}

// ADD NEW COLUMN
function pkb_columns_head($defaults) {
    $defaults['excerpt'] = 'excerpt';
    return $defaults;
}

// SHOW THE EXCERPT
function pkb_columns_content($column_name, $post_ID) {
    if ($column_name == 'excerpt') {
        $post_content = pkb_get_excerpt($post_ID);
        echo $str1= substr ($post_content,0,50);

    }
}

add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'pkb_columns_head');
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'pkb_columns_content', 10, 2);
```

Please feel free to ask if you have any queries.

Comment: Thank you! Its working. Do you know How can I print specific columns? Or get them on a separate page. I want to print post title, excerpt and Post id.

Comment: Do you mean you need to display it in frontend?  I did not understand your query

Comment: Yes i need to print it on the front end.